# How to remove null values elements from model list in C#?

Tags: c#, list

I try to Extract data using LINQ query and adding into a model list.In this list only I need some of the fields values, but it's returning all the table fields include with null values. I have use model first approach so all the model classes will create the get set methods with all the table fields name so I want to remove some fields when I am retrieving the data Is it possible??

This my code

```
for (var z = 0; z < room_ament_list.Count(); z++)    
{
     var deal_room_amentity_id = room_ament_list[z];
     var deal_room_amentity_details = db.deal_room_amentity.Where(a => a.room_amenity_id == deal_room_amentity_id).ToList();

     foreach (var item_r_amentity in deal_room_amentity_details)
     {
         deal_room_amentity_list.Add(new deal_room_amentity()
         {
           room_amenity_id = item_r_amentity.room_amenity_id,
           amenity_type = item_r_amentity.amenity_type,
         });
     }
}
```

this my table structure

[image: table structure in my database]

And this is returning data from that list

[image: returning data from the list]

But I need to Extract the data of what I have assigned in the list(without null elements).Is it possible to remove those null value element from the list??

Comment: Do you mean where amenity_type == null ?

Comment: I want to remove ImagePath and id from the list I need only what I have assigned the value when adding to the list (room_amenity_id, amenity_type)

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding your question correctly, you could modify you LINQ query as follows:

```
var deal_room_amentity_details = db.deal_room_amentity
     .Where(a => a.room_amenity_id == deal_room_amentity_id 
     && a.room_amenity_id != null).ToList();
```

Comment: I want to remove ImagePath and id from the list I need only what I have assigned the value when adding to the list (room_amenity_id, amenity_type)

Answer (score 0):

You can download just the information you need from a SQL table by specifying an object definition in your `Linq` query.

```
 var data = from x in db.deal_room_amentity
         where 
              x.room_amenity_id == deal_room_amentity_id
         select new {
              id = x.id,
              room_amenity_id = x.room_amenity_id
         };
    foreach(var item_r_amentity in data){
         deal_room_amentity_list.Add(new deal_room_amentity()
             {
               room_amenity_id = item_r_amentity.room_amenity_id,
               amenity_type = item_r_amentity.amenity_type,
             });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but this also returning same result I want to remove ImagePath and id from the deal_room_amentity_list is their any way???

Comment: The syntax above will work for any of the fields you want to select, and you can apply the results from `data` into any custom entity of your choosing. `ImagePath` and `id` don't even have to appear in your code.